# regex for only lowercase letters and underscore

Tags: javascript, regex, quasar

I'm trying to validate a field called "role" where the pattern's type is only names like this: super_user, computer_group. But not this: "admin_area_" or "Admin_area??", "ADMIN_".
Only lowercase letters and underscore between those letters, never on final. This is what i tried until now:

`/^[a-z]+(_*[a-z]+)*$/` and `/^[a-z_]*$/`

But for some reason, when the user types "??" or any other character my validation is still allowing those characters.

***NOTE:*** my inputs are from quasar framework where I validate that in `:rules`

Comment: The first regex looks like it covers all your test cases pretty well https://regex101.com/r/Ip5LNf/1

Comment: hmmm weird... well, i think i not tested it very well

Comment: So `super_user_person` is valid or invalid? Ditto for `super__user` and `username`

Comment: @Taxel `_*` is a very inefficient choice

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I agree, but that was not the question. I would suggest turning `_*` (zero or multiple underscores) into `_?` (zero or one underscore) and also turn the capturing into a non-capture group, so all in all I would suggest `/^[a-z]+(?:_?[a-z]+)*$/`

Comment: @Taxel That's just as bad. Switch to PHP or Python at regex101 and look at the "steps" in the upper right. Now try `^[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*$` and you will see a 10 fold difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> your first  regex is working well still you can try this one.
> it won't allow without underscore.

```
^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Flash Noob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65848827/5211833), validates `??` too. Instead, you can use:

```
^[a-z]+(?:_{0,2}[a-z]+)*$
```

Comment: `The answer by Flash Noob, validates ??` please clarify. Since the other answer accepts a minimum of 3 characters (and won’t accept any literal `?`) - I think there’s a misunderstanding here. Note also this regex [doesn’t do what is asked](https://regex101.com/r/6Q9nlT/1) and is almost identical to a regex discussed in the question comments.